# In Django how can I influence the connection process to the DB?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

What is the best method to change the way how `django` connects to the DB (i.e. MySQL)?

For instance what should I do if I needed `django` to connect to the db via `ssh` tunnel, whose settings may change dynamically? (I'm planning to use [sshtunnel](https://sshtunnel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/))

I understand I should `sub-class` the `django.db.backends.mysql.base.DatabaseWrapper` and probably `super()`/modify the `get_new_connection(self, conn_params)`? (see the example below)

But then how would I submit this custom `class` in the settings, as it seems that the settings expect path to the module, rather than the class?

Something among the lines:

```
class myDatabaseWrapper(DatabaseWrapper):
    """Oversimplified example."""
    def get_new_connection(self, conn_params):
        with open('path/to/json.js', 'rt') as file: 
            my_conn_params = json.load(file)
        conn_params.update(my_conn_params) 
        return super().get_new_connection(my_conn_params)
```

Comment: Settings changing might cause you trouble, but I'd start by looking at this; https://github.com/mvx24/django-dbtunnel

Comment: @markwalker_ Thank you for the suggestion. I'm not going to modify `settings` dynamically, but rather connection parameters, as shown in the edited question. So that every time a new db connections needs to be established (or re-established), settings for that connection can be updated.

Comment: Perhaps it can be done by sending a signal whenever you are about to connect to the db, and establish an SSH connection at that point. Might be worth looking in to. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/signals/#defining-and-sending-signals